# How to configure multiple tables into kafka topic using routing

Tags: regex, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I have a db with n tenants that has a mongo collection for each tenant. I want to add all tables to a debezium connector and link them to one topic specified. ex

- tenant1.circles->circleTopic,
- tenant2.circles->circleTopic
- tenant1.triangle->triangleTopic
- tenant2.triangle->triangleTopic

I tried with one collection to one topic and it works fine and it works fine if I add more collections to the first topic but I'm lost on how to add  the second part.

Example that works fine for only 1 collection.

```
 "collection.whitelist": "tenant1.triangle, tenant2.triangle, tenant3.triangle",
 "transforms": "regexRouter",
 "transforms.regexRouter.regex": "(.*)",
 "transforms.regexRouter.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.RegexRouter",
 "transforms.regexRouter.replacement": "triangleTopic"
```

Now what I want is in collection whitelist to add like a second collection and go to a separate topic.

I'm kinda new to this debezium connector and transform stuff and reading online did not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try something like

```
"transforms.regexRouter.regex": "tenant\d+\.([a-z]+)s?",
"transforms.regexRouter.replacement": "$1Topic"
```

https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/transforms/regexrouter.html

Note that this may result in `circlesTopic`, not `circleTopic`

Comment: This helped me but in the end I added 2 transforms
"transforms": "triangle,circle",
 and in the end i added regex for each one. Thanks